# Total number of unique permissions per list

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, security

The http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787.aspx specifies the total number of unique security scopes to 50.000/list, but recommended is 5.000/list.
In a list, is it possible to find out the total number of security scopes used?

Either with powershell or .NET

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got a script from this site http://www.mysharepointadventures.com/2011/08/powershell-script-to-display-unique-permissions-for-all-subsites-and-lists/

```
Syntax: <script name>.ps1 | out-file c:\permissions.txt

#Add SharePoint PowerShell SnapIn if not already added
if ((Get-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -eq $null) {
    Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"
}

#Define variables
$site = Get-SPSite "http://<site collection>"

#Get all subsites for site collection
$web = $site.AllWebs

#Loop through each subsite and write permissions

foreach ($web in $web)
{
    if (($web.permissions -ne $null) -and ($web.hasuniqueroleassignments -eq "True"))
    {
        Write-Output "****************************************"
        Write-Output "Displaying site permissions for: $web"
        $web.permissions | fl member, basepermissions
    }
    elseif ($web.hasuniqueroleassignments -ne "True")
    {
        Write-Output "****************************************"
        Write-Output "Displaying site permissions for: $web"
        "$web inherits permissions from $site"
    }

        #Loop through each list in each subsite and get permissions
    foreach ($list in $web.lists)
    {
        $unique = $list.hasuniqueroleassignments
        if (($list.permissions -ne $null) -and ($unique -eq "True"))
        {
            Write-Output "****************************************"
            Write-Output "Displaying Lists permissions for: $web \ $list"
            $list.permissions | fl member, basepermissions
        }
        elseif ($unique -ne "True") 
        {
            Write-Output "$web \ $list inherits permissions from $web"
        }
    }
}

Write-Host "Finished."
$site.dispose()
$web.dispose()
$unique.dispose()
```

For ListItems you can enhance the above and use

```
foreach ($item in $list.Items)
{
    if($item.hasuniqueroleassignments -eq "True")
    {
         Write-Host "Unique Item"
    }   
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I think this one shows the unique permissions that a list has. I want to know the total number of security scopes  on the item level. A list can have unique permissions, but I can set programmatically unique permissions on item level - this will not propagate to list level.

Comment: You can place another loop inside the `foreach ($list` where you iterate through all the `listitems` and do the same check. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitem.hasuniqueroleassignments.ASPX

Comment: @XristosK I have updated my answer

Answer (score 2):

I recommend to use a count variable to get the total count of unique permission for the list.

foreach ($item in $list.Items)
{
    if($item.hasuniqueroleassignments -eq "True")
    {
         *$count++*
         Write-Host "Unique Item"
    }
}